Woocommerce - do action BEFORE sending completed order email
I have an ACF custom field on the order screen in Woocommerce. The content of this field gets pulled into the woocommerce Completed order email.
Currently, I have to add text to the custom field, hit "Update" on the post, then switch to Completed, then hit "Update" again.
I want to eliminate the double Updates, so I am trying to save the post and/or fields BEFORE the Completed order email fires. I've tried this:
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'save_post_on_competed_status', 9, 4);
function save_post_on_competed_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'completed' ) {
       do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );
    }
}

I thought maybe I could get it to save the post earlier, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

By default (some plugins may change this behaviour), WooCommerce uses the woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification action hook to send the Completed Order Email:
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );

So you can try to utilize this hook but use a priority number lower than 10. In this case, your code will be executed before the email is sent.
